# Why can I not define main() first, and then the functions which it calls?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, forward-declaration, code-organization

If I put main on the top of the source file and invoke some custom functions, it will tell me that those functions are not found, but if I put main on the bottom of the source file, it will work.

Why? Is it because the compiler parses the program from top to bottom and breaks at the definition of main?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has nothing to do with main. C++ compilers work top to bottom, period.

Anything that you reference needs to be declared previously. The same goes for variables. In your case, you could do

```
void foo();     // <-- Forward declaration, aka prototype

int main() {
   foo();
}

void foo() {
   // Here is your foo implementation.
}
```

Comment: The standard terminology for that "forward declaration" (when you're forward-declaring a function) is a **prototype**, and *every* function should have one.

Comment: Short answer, just perfect. So good it makes me almost cry out of luck :')

Comment: This has a C++ flag, so you definitely should *not* say void main().

Comment: I think as an example, it does the trick.
As Ken said - it's common practice to have a header file (.h) with all the prototypes, and the implementations in the .cpp file. Better yet, since we're talking C++, everything is in classes, and you don't have global functions.

Comment: @EboMike no global functions?! So the main function should be I'm a class too??

Comment: @EboMike: First of all, this is C++, not Java, so everything does not have to be in classes. Second, look at this on void main: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: @Ken: it would be a prototype in C. In C++, it's just a declaration (and C++ doesn't have anything that corresponds to what C calls a function declaration).

Comment: No, main is special. And it really depends on what you do. But global functions are what you will use C - for C++, it's /typically/ cleaner to use classes. Again, it's all about what you're doing.

Comment: @EboMike: Pardon me French, bit that's bullshit. C++ is a __multi-paradigm__ language, and OO is but one paradigms it supports. Free functions can actually enhance encapsulation. Making everything a member function simply is an implementation artifact on languages which lack support for non-member functions.

Comment: @EboMike:  [Where possible, prefer writing functions as nonmember nonfriends.](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm)

Comment: @Ken: "prototype" is not really a concept in C++. There is only one way to declare a function, giving its full signature, and that is called a "declaration". C-style declarations, omitting the parameter types, are not valid, since they are incompatible with overloading.

Comment: @Mike, @Jerry: The C++0x draft refers to prototypes in numerous places, for example 3.3.2, 3.3.4, 17.5.1.4, 20.7.4.3 (par 6), 20.7.5. Additionally, wikipedia says that "A function prototype in C or C++ is a declaration of a function that omits the function body but does specify the function's name, arity, argument types and return type," and that C function prototypes were originally taken from C++. The C99 draft N869 (6.7.5.3 examples 4 and 5), uses the term prototype to refer to function declaractions that specify the types of the parameters. **So I am right to call it a prototype in C++.**

Comment: @Ken: Sorry to continue the pedantry, which is getting rather tedious now. The C++ Standard does, for some bizarre reason, call the scope of names in a function declaration "function prototype scope", and uses the term informally in a few places. But the formal specification of the grammar doesn't define anything with the name "prototype". C does have separate concepts of "declaration" and "prototype", as you say, but that's irrelevant to a question about a different language. So call it a prototype if you like, but don't claim that it's standard C++ terminology.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, yes. You have to define/declare  a function before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting your functions signature into header files that are included before main().

Answer (score 0):

If main is declared before your custom functions, by the time main gets parsed it hasn't 'seen' any definitions for them.